# Parsing info revealed on button click

Tags: python, ajax, parsing, python-requests

I'm trying to parse this page: https://www.website.com/details/

There is a phone number button  hiding the part of the
phone number. On click, ajax post request brings in the complete phone number.

How can I fake this post request in python?

import requests, time, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7",
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
}
s = requests.Session()

response = s.get(
"https://www.mashina.kg/details/kia-sorento-64631fe26592a662606296", headers=headers
)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")

Comment: Sounds like a Selenium task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.mashina.kg/details/kia-sorento-64631fe26592a662606296'

headers  = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url + '/givemereal', headers=headers).content, 'html.parser')
for n in soup.select('.number'):
    print(n.text)
```

This will print the telephone numbers.